# How can I store a pattern in a variable in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm implementing a parser in Rust and whitespace is a common pattern that I want to reuse in `match` patterns.

This code works:

```
let ch = ' ';

match ch {
    ' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r' => println!("whitespace"),
     _ => println!("token"),
}
```

This would get really repetitive if I need to keep on specifying the whitespace pattern each time.  I would like to define that once and reuse it.  I want to do something like:

```
let whitespace = ' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r';

let ch = ' ';

match ch {
    whitespace => println!("whitespace"),
    _          => println!("token"),
}
```

The compiler does not like the `ws` assignment.  It interprets the `|` as a binary operation instead of alternation.

Can patterns be stored in variables somehow?  Is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: In C this would look like a good candidate for a macro, wonder if macro is the way to go in Rust too...

Comment: @turbulencetoo an interesting idea. In C, a macro is lower-level text manipulation, which can result in invalid source code. In Rust, the number of places you can invoke a macro is limited and the expansion must be syntactically valid. I don't think that patterns are in the set of valid places. You could always do some type of build script to generate text files that happen to result in valid Rust code, however.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Can patterns be stored in variables somehow?

No. Patterns are a compile-time construct, and variables hold run-time concepts.

> Is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this?

Creating a function or method is always a good solution to avoid repeating code. You can then use this as a *guard clause*:

```
fn is_whitespace(c: char) -> bool {
    match c {
        ' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r' => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ch = ' ';

    match ch {
        x if is_whitespace(x) => println!("whitespace"),
        _ => println!("token"),
    }
}
```

---

I'd also strongly recommend using an existing parser, [of which there are a multitude](https://crates.io/categories/parsing), but everyone wants their Rust "hello world" to be parsing, for whatever reason.

A parsing library I use allows writing code akin to this, where `whitespace` is a function that knows how to parse the valid types of whitespace:

```
sequence!(pm, pt, {
    _          = literal("if");
    ws         = whitespace;
    _          = literal("let");
    ws         = append_whitespace(ws);
    pattern    = pattern;
    ws         = optional_whitespace(ws);
    _          = literal("=");
    ws         = optional_whitespace(ws);
    expression = expression;
}, |_, _| /* do something with pieces */);
```

Each of the things on the right-hand side are still individual functions that know how to parse something specific.

Comment: Will the guard clause version have the same performance? For example, would it prevent the main match expression being compiled to a single jump table?

Comment: @张实唯 that assumes that it would be a jump table to start with. I don't know that there are any guarantees you can assume here. Profiling and looking at the generated code is the best path.