# How do I use a const range in a match statement?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

This works:

```rust
match 0 {
    0..=9 => (),
    _ => (),
}
```

But this doesn't:

```rust
const R: std::ops::RangeInclusive<u8> = 0..=9;

fn main() {
    match 0 {
        R => (),
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2eb47cb2a3b4ad208ad88b8fa552b885).

If I want to use a range with `match`, must I use a literal range?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How can I store a pattern in a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42793606/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you `match` an `u8`, each match arm must offer values of type `u8` that can be compared to the parameter.

Now, if you write `0..=9`, this is not a `RangeInclusive` (even if it looks the same) - it is a [*range pattern*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#range-patterns) that can be used to describe a range of values in a match arm.

So, if you write `R => ()` in a match arm, the compiler complains (imo rightfully):

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |         R => (),
  |         ^ expected integer, found struct `std::ops::RangeInclusive`
  |
  = note: expected type `u8`
             found type `std::ops::RangeInclusive<u8>`
```

I.e. it expects a `u8` (or, implicitly, a range pattern for `u8` values), but it found a `RangeInclusive`.

Now, one possible solution could be to define the lower and upper bound as separate constants:

```
const LOWER : u8 = 0;
const UPPER : u8 = 9;
const R: std::ops::RangeInclusive<u8> = LOWER..=UPPER; // <- this is a RangeInclusive<u8>

fn main() {
    match 0 {
        LOWER..=UPPER => (), // <- this is a range pattern
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

Another, in my opinion less appealing, would be a macro that just expands to your range:

```
macro_rules! myrng{() => {0..=9}}
const R: std::ops::RangeInclusive<u8> = myrng!();

fn main() {
    match 0 {
        myrng!() => (),
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a wart of the language, seeing as it uses the identical `..=` syntax.

Comment: @puritii Believe it or not, the pattern syntax used to be different (it was `0...9`, with three dots), but that old syntax was deprecated in favor of using `..` and `..=` for both patterns and ranges.