# How do I match based on a dynamic variable?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Is it possible to match on a dynamic variable instead of only literals?

In this code, the first `match` should do the same as the commented out `match` (`number[0]` being `0` and `number[1]` being `1`):

```
const NUMBERS: [i8; 2] = [0, 1];

fn test() {
    let current = 5;

    let string = match current % 2 {
        NUMBERS[0] => "even", // This does not work
        NUMBERS[1] => "odd",  // This does not work
        _ => unreachable!(),
    };

    // let string = match current % 2 {
    //     0 => "even",
    //     1 => "odd",
    //     _ => unreachable!()
    // };
}
```

Comment: Related: [How can I store a pattern in a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793606/how-can-i-store-a-pattern-in-a-variable-in-rust)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [*Match guards*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html#match-guards).

```
let string = match current % 2 {
    even if even == numbers[0] => "even",
    odd if odd == numbers[1] => "odd",
    _ => unreachable!()
};
```

Comment: You can also omit the guard from the second branch, since there is no way of the guard failing to match. Once you do, you don't need the unreachable third branch anymore.

Answer (score 6):

> is it possible in rust to match on a dynamic variable

No. As the name implies, *pattern-matching* works on the basis of *patterns*, not *expressions* or *values*.

You can see this from [the grammar](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html): a *MatchArm* is *OuterAttribute* Pattern MatchArmGuard?*, and [a pattern is an enumerated set of specific constructs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html). Mostly literals, identifiers, paths, and ways to combine those (structs, tuples, slice, ... patterns).

Answer (score 3):

Despite what the other answers say, it *is* possible to do what you want, but you need to make an explicitly named constant for each case.

```rust
const numbers: [i8; 2] = [
    0, 1
];

fn test() {
    let current = 5;
    
    const NUMBERS0: i8 = numbers[0];
    const NUMBERS1: i8 = numbers[1];

    let string = match current % 2 {
        NUMBERS0 => "even",   // This does not work
        NUMBERS1 => "odd",    // This does not work
        _ => unreachable!()
    };

    // let string = match current % 2 {
    //     0 => "even",
    //     1 => "odd",
    //     _ => unreachable!()
    // };
}
```

This works only because your expressions are `const`. Non-`const` expressions cannot be used in patterns.
The intermediary `NUMBERS0` and `NUMBERS1` constants are necessary for syntax reasons. The left side of `=>` is not an expression but a pattern. Some patterns look like expressions, but not all expressions have a pattern lookalike.

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the value then pass to `match`

```
const numbers: [i8; 2] = [0, 1];
let current = 5;

let string = match numbers[current % 2] {
    0 => "even",
    1 => "odd",   
    _ => unreachable!()
};
println!("{}",string);
```