# How to use values from an array in matching ranges of values with ..= in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm learning rust and I found something I can't just find in google.
I was experimenting with match and I wanted to use values from an array with the ..= syntax.
I know I'm doing something wrong, but I only know Js and Python and I feel I'm missing something basic that it's just known but not explained.

```
    pub fn match_statement() {
    println!("Match statement----------------------------------");
    let mut country_code=0;
    let country_codes_range: [i64; 4] = [1,999,50,66];
    let country = match country_code {
        34 => "Spain",
        46 => "Sweden",
        country_codes_range[0]..=country_codes_range[1] => "unknown",
        _ => "invalid",
    };
    country_code=invalid_country;
    println!(
        "The {} country code is {} because is out of the range [{},{}]",
        country, invalid_country, country_codes_range[0], country_codes_range[1]
    );
}
```

the error I get is:
expected one of `=>`, `@`, `if`, or `|`, found `[`
on the line
country_codes_range[0]..=country_codes_range[1] => "unknown"

I don't know if the issue lies in my calling of items of the array, an incorrect use of ..= or another thing

Also, I guess I would get a similar error if I used a tuple instead of an array?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I match based on a dynamic variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70344352/how-do-i-match-based-on-a-dynamic-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust needs to know the "values" of each match arm *at compile time*, so what you're describing isn't possible, instead you'll get an error saying `runtime values cannot be references in patterns`.

If you know what `country_codes_range` will be at compile time, you can make it available at compile time using `const`:

```rust
fn match_statement() {
  let country_code = 123;

  const COUNTRY_CODES_RANGE: [i64; 4] = [1, 999, 50, 66];
  const FIRST: i64 = COUNTRY_CODES_RANGE[0];
  const SECOND: i64 = COUNTRY_CODES_RANGE[1];

  let country = match country_code {
    34 => "spain",
    46 => "sweden",
    FIRST..=SECOND => "unknown",
    _ => "invalid",
  };
  
  // ...
}
```

Note, the intermediate consts `FIRST` and `SECOND` are needed because currently Rust's parser doesn't support the `a[i]` syntax in patterns, though that is a separate problem to having a match use runtime values