# Strange matching behaviour in for loop

Tags: rust

Rust noob here. I am puzzled as to why I get this strange behaviour when matching the variable over which I am iterating through a range, with the max of that range. Instead of only matching with the last item, it matches everything! Can someone please explain the output and compiler warning I get from this code:

```rs
fn main() {
  let maxi = 2;
  for i in 0..=maxi {
    match i {
      maxi => {
        println!("i={} matched maxi={}",i,maxi);
      }
      _ => {
        println!("i={} matched with _",i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler output is as follows

```rs
warning: unreachable pattern
 --> se_match_loop.rs:7:15
  |
5 |             maxi => {
  |             ---- matches any value
6 |                 println!("i={} matched maxi={}",i,maxi);
7 |             } _ => {
  |               ^ unreachable pattern
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unreachable_patterns)]` on by default

warning: 1 warning emitted
```

When I execute the compiled script, this is the output

```
i=0 matched maxi=0
i=1 matched maxi=1
i=2 matched maxi=2
```

But if I declare `maxi` as a constant (with `const` instead of `let`), I get the expected output

```
i=0 matched _
i=1 matched _
i=2 matched maxi=2
```

Comment: Related: [How do I match based on a dynamic variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70344352/how-do-i-match-based-on-a-dynamic-variable)

Answer (score 7):

This is documented under [*Matching Named Variables*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#matching-named-variables)<sup>doc.rust-lang.org</sup>.

> `match` starts a new scope, variables declared as part of a pattern
> inside the `match` expression will shadow those with the same name
> outside the match construct, as is the case with all variables.
>
> For example, the following code
>
> ```
> fn main() {
>     let x = Some(5);
>     let y = 10;
>
>     match x {
>         Some(50) => println!("Got 50"),
>         Some(y) => println!("Matched, y = {:?}", y),
>         _ => println!("Default case, x = {:?}", x),
>     }
>
>     println!("at the end: x = {:?}, y = {:?}", x, y);
> }
> ```
>
> will print
>
> ```
> Matched, y = 5
> at the end: x = Some(5), y = 10
> ```

Now let's consider your first snippet,

```
fn main() {
  let maxi = 2;
  for i in 0..=maxi {
    match i {
      maxi => {
        println!("i={} matched maxi={}",i,maxi);
      }
      _ => {
        println!("i={} matched with _",i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The pattern in your `match` arm *introduces a new variable(Remember `match` started with a new scope) named `maxi` that will match any value*. That's why the rust compiler emits the following warning with your first snippet.

```
warning: unreachable pattern
 --> se_match_loop.rs:7:15
  |
5 |             maxi => {
  |             ---- matches any value
6 |                 println!("i={} matched maxi={}",i,maxi);
7 |             } _ => {
  |               ^ unreachable pattern
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unreachable_patterns)]` on by default

warning: 1 warning emitted
```

Now lets consider the second one(with `const`),

```
fn main() {
  const maxi: i32 = 2;
  for i in 0..=maxi {
    match i {
      maxi => {
        println!("i={} matched maxi={}",i,maxi);
      }
      _ => {
        println!("i={} matched with _",i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will work as expected because [constants are inlined wherever they’re used, making using them identical to simply replacing the name of the `const` with its value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.const.html#compile-time-constants)<sup>doc.rust-lang.org</sup>