# Error while using tuple elements for match statement comparison

Tags: rust

i'm trying to match two variables with elements of a tuple but I'm not sure what's the error here.

```
fn main() {

    let s = "cloudy";
    let t = "warm";
    
    let sky = ("cloudy", "sunny", "rainy");
    let temperature = ("warm", "cold", "freezing");

    match (s,t) {
        (sky.0, temperature.0) => println!("It's cloudy and warm"),
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do not post text as images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I match based on a dynamic variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70344352/how-do-i-match-based-on-a-dynamic-variable)

Comment: Ok @ChayimFriedman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [match expression documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html), the left side of a match expression needs to be a [pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html).

Sadly, dynamic variables do not count as patterns. If you have a variable on the left side, the pattern matching will try to destructure data *into* it instead.

---

### Solution #1: If Statements

If you absolutely need to match with a dynamic variable, the only way I see is to use `if` statements:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = "cloudy";
    let t = "warm";

    let sky = ("cloudy", "sunny", "rainy");
    let temperature = ("warm", "cold", "freezing");

    if s == sky.0 && t == temperature.0 {
        println!("It's cloudy and warm")
    }
}
```

---

### Solution #2: Literals

If you want to do pattern matching on strings, you need to use `string literals`.

Further, the `match` statement needs to be exhaustive, meaning, it must cover every possibility. So in your case the easiest way to achieve that is to use the `_` pattern to match everything that hasn't been matched before.

This is also one of the reasons dynamic variables can't be used in match patterns: The compiler does not yet know the content of those variables, so it cannot check if the match is exhaustive.

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = "cloudy";
    let t = "warm";

    match (s, t) {
        ("cloudy", "warm") => println!("It's cloudy and warm"),
        _ => println!("It isn't cloudy and warm"),
    }
}
```

---

### Solution #3: Enums

The third solution, and the one you probably *intended* to do by defining the `sky` and `temperature` variables, is to use `enum`s.

But just as previously, the `match` statement needs to be exhaustive and therefore we need to add the `_` case.

```rust
pub enum Sky {
    Cloudy,
    Sunny,
    Rainy,
}

pub enum Temperature {
    Warm,
    Cold,
    Freezing,
}

fn main() {
    let s = Sky::Cloudy;
    let t = Temperature::Warm;

    match (s, t) {
        (Sky::Cloudy, Temperature::Warm) => println!("It's cloudy and warm"),
        _ => println!("It isn't cloudy and warm"),
    }
}
```

If you have strings as input values, you can of course then implement the `FromStr` trait for those enums to convert the strings into an enum value.