# Apparent unused variable in match statement

Tags: rust, enums, match

I am implementing a simple library system to keep track of my pdfs.

I have a `Subject` enum and a `Entry` struct defined as follows:

```
pub enum Subject {

    Math,
    Programming,
    CompSci,
    Language,
    Misc,
    None
}

pub struct Entry {

    pub subject: Subject

}
```

I am trying to implement a function that will operate on a vector of `Entry`'s and return a `Vec<&Entry>` whose entries match a given `Subject`.

I have a simple `Library` struct that is a wrapper around a `Vec<Entry>`:

```
pub struct Library {

    pub entries: Vec<Entry>

}
```

In order to do so, I need to iterate through `entries` and `filter` only the elements whose `.subject` field correspond to the desired `subject`. To accomplish this I have created a function that will *return* a predicate function.

Here is the `get_subject` function:

```
impl Library {
    
    pub fn get_subject(&self, subject: Subject) -> Vec<&Entry> {

        let pred = subject_pred(subject);
        self.entries.iter().filter(pred).collect::<Vec<&Entry>>()
    }
}
```

which calls the function `subject_pred` to create the correct predicate function:

```
// Return a PREDICATE that returns true when
// the passed ENTRY matches the desired SUBJECT
fn subject_pred(subject_UNUSED: Subject) -> impl FnMut(&&Entry) -> bool {
    |e: &&Entry| if matches!(&e.subject, subject_UNUSED) {
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

**Here's** the problem. This syntax compiles just fine but apparently the `subject_UNUSED` local variable in `subject_pred` is "unused". I am flabbergasted as my syntax clearly shows intent to match with the passed `subject_UNUSED`. When I test out this function on a vector of entries, the predicate **always** returns true (hence why I am receiving the "unused" warning) but I have literally no idea why.

If anyone could explain why the `match` statement is always matched, that would be greatly appreciated. I tried using a regular `match` statement but the same warning is popping up, and this is not the behavior that I am trying to code. If I don't include the `subject_UNUSED` in a traditional `match` statement, the compiler tells me that I have to cover the `Math`, `Programming`, `CompSci`, `Language`, `Misc` and `None` variants of my enum, which indicates to me that everything up until that point is good.

Comment: This signatue - `pub fn get_subject(entries: Vec<Entry>, subject: Subject) -> Vec<&Entry>` - is not going to work: you cannot take an owned `Entry` and produce a borrowed one.

Comment: I actually have a `Library` structure that is simply a wrapper around a `Vec<Entry>` but I didn't want to include it to complicate things.

I'll include them in an edit for transparency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this match pattern unreachable when using non-literal patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225958/why-is-this-match-pattern-unreachable-when-using-non-literal-patterns)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot match against a variable. What you've done is equivalent to

```rust
matches!(&e.subject, some_subject)
```

That matches *any* `Subject`, just like a wildcard (`_`), except it also captures it in the `some_subject` variable (can be used in a guard like `matches!(&e.subject, subject_UNUSED if subject_UNUSED == ...)`). Neither the captured variable nor the parameter (which is shadowed by it) are used.

What you need to do is to `#[derive(PartialEq)]` then use `==`:

```rust
if e.subject == subject_UNUSED { ... }
```

By the way, your code also has other problems: you don't `move` into the closure and you're taking owned entries but produce borrowed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I started off with a simple `==` but moved to a `match` because that's what I've seen done when "comparing" enums.

I'll use `#[derive(PartialEq)]` as a solution. I also had a `move` statement previously in the closure but since that "didn't change anything" (from my ignorant standpoint) I removed it.

I'm just kinda stumbling through the language and finding it far more difficult then anything I've learned in the past. "You cannot match against a variable" isn't mentioned in the book.

Comment: @ejovo13 Well, it's been long since I learned Rust, but looking at the book, it does mention that you match against patterns and I don't think it says a variable is a pattern.

Comment: I get your point but my counter is that the value stored in my variable will very much be an enum variant so it's not at all unreasonable to assume that I can match against something that is effectively a pattern.

It's like saying that I can't expect 
`let x = 10; println!("{}", x);`
to print out the value `10` because I'm not actually passing the value `10` rather I'm passing a variable...

The point is I'm not hating on the authors of the book - it's amazing - it's just one of those things that you only learn the limitations of the language when you try something tthat doesnt work.

Comment: @ejovo13 Well what you're storing in the variable is not a pattern ([you can't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793606/how-can-i-store-a-pattern-in-a-variable-in-rust)) but a value, and the `10` (or the enum variant) you're assigning in the variable declaration is not a pattern but an expression. However, arguing about that is pretty redundant. Now you understand and that is the important thing.

Comment: Not intending to argue! It's a learning process and yes now I understand and that's what's important :). Just giving in to my primitive desire to defend myself ;). Thanks again for the help.